# boost::variant and void* pointers

Tags: c++, boost, variant, void-pointers

I need a variant type that holds instances of any user-defined class. So I use void*:

```
typedef boost::variant<void*, int, float, std::string> Tvariant;
```

I've created a wrapper class with a map:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Tvariant> Tvalues;
```

Example of usage:

```
int x = 123;
attributes.set("int_var", x);
x = attributes.get<int>("int_var");

MyClass* obj = new MyClass();
attributes.set("void*_var", obj);
obj = static_cast<MyClass*>( attributes.get<void*>("void*_var") );
obj = attributes.cast<MyClass*>("void*_var"); // the same
```

There are 2 issues with this void* in variant class:

1. Copying attributes with pointers to dynamically allocated memory is dangerous and error-prone.
2. User can static_cast void* to WrongClass*, not to MyClass*. It compiles, but result is unpredicted.

Possible solutions:

1. Use boost::shared_ptr< void* >.
2. Remember typeid for all void* values (when they are added) in the `std::map<void*, typeid> typeid_map`. When user requests for void* value, casting it to any TClass*, let's evaluate an assertion: `assert(typeid_from_typeid_map == typeid(TClass*))`.

---

**Questions**:
1. Are there other solutions to hold values of any user-defined class?
2. May be you will recommend better solutions for mentioned issues and point some other issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you look at [Boost::Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/any.html)?  This is something that carries with it compile time knowledge of the casting of the type while hiding what type it really is via the Any.

Comment: Yes, but boost::any does not provide compile-time checks and is slower than boost::variant. Does boost::any provide type safety when casting any-value to user-defined class?

Comment: @topright Since you are already using Boost, boost::any seems the way to go.

Comment: @topright: `boost::any` provides run time type checking, and `any_cast` requires you to specify the type you want to retrieve, eg. `Myclass* c = any_cast<MyClass*>(myMap["myClassObj"])`, which throws `bad_any_cast` if you were wrong about the type. Since you will be looking up values in a map, I doubt the overhead of `boost::any` will be relevant to you. Boost any is syntactically very clean, and very safe.

Comment: @topright gamedev I'm sorry I didn't have time to flesh out my answer in a more explanatory manner.  I generally only post when I need a few minutes of downtime, the weekends, or off work hours.

Comment: @wheaties, that's okey, I already knew about boost::any and I just changed my implementation to use it. What I was concerned about is performance and type safety.